# Why my PC slow down?

Tags: performance

I'm using:

Kubuntu 18.04 : 32-bit

- Hardware
  Processor: 2* Pentium@ Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GH
- Memory: 1.9 GiB of RAM

I'm a developer and so I use Java, NetBeans, MySQL, Valentina DB.
But I can not do multitasking it freeze a lot.

When I open Chromium it almost takes 15-20 seconds to load.
It is also freeze while other heavy apps are open.
Even I have make swap partition but it doesn't help much.

Same for Windows 7.
How can I increase my PC performance?

Comment: Get a new one. Your PC has too little of everything.

Comment: So no benefits if I would increase RAM size?

Comment: The processor was launched in 2008, according to its Intel ARK page.  You can slightly improve performance by acquiring 8 GB or 16 GB of RAM, but then the CPU will be the bottleneck.  You probably have a hard disk, which can be replaced by an SSD, but again, the CPU will be the bottleneck.

Comment: As I think about it, getting more RAM might be hard.  The ARK page shows that the CPU is 64-bit capable, but you would have to install a new 64 bit OS.  And I don't know if the motherboard supports more RAM.  Again, getting a more modern PC is best.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherHostage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to a 64-bit OS. This will let you use more RAM.

Increase the amount of RAM you have. For multitasking to the extent you are around 8Gb should be fine. Anything less and its almost the same issue as 2gb and anything more will probably wasted unless you are using intensive programs.

Get an SSD if you haven't already. This is probably the best upgrade you can get. The difference in speed is incredible. They are coming down in price for more storage as well so now might as well be the time to upgrade.

You could probably do with upgrading the processor, but if cost is an issue then I would leave this to last. Its not the greatest spec you have but it should be fine until everything else is upgraded.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes you are right it looks like need to upgrade everything. I tried 64 bit OS even Win 7 is 64 bit OS but performance is same. I was thinking two upgrade with 2GB x 2 RAMs.

Answer (score -1):

When computer works it start making temporary files and caches
For window go to start, run, open- temp, %temp% , recent. Delete all file which can able to delete
This make your computer little faster

Comment: I also use linux which doesn't need to delete temp like thing.